# SQL domain ERROR: column does not exist, setting default

Tags: sql, postgresql, string-constant

I created a DOMAIN:

```
CREATE DOMAIN public."POSTAL_CODE"
  AS character(5)
  NOT NULL;
```

I tried to set the default value:

```
ALTER DOMAIN public."POSTAL_CODE"
SET DEFAULT "00000";
```

but got the error:

> ERROR:  column "00000" does not exist

Then I managed to set the default value using `DEFAULT 00000`, but I think it was cast to `INTEGER` as it shows as `0` instead of `00000`. I tried `character(5)[]` and  `{'0','0','0','0','0'}` without success as well.

How to get a default value as text and not get an error?

I used PostgreSQL.

Comment: Simply `'00000'`. (Double quotes are for delimited identifiers. Use single quotes for string literals.)

Comment: It works, @jarlh. Thanks!

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In SQL double quotes `"` [are used](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS) to refer to a column or table named "select"

A [string constant](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS) in SQL is an arbitrary sequence of characters bounded by single quotes (`'`), for example `'This is a string'`. So  this is not the same as a double-quote character (`"`)

As a result you have to use single quote like below

```
select * from test where old_code = '220088242'
```

so in your case  it should be like below

```
ALTER DOMAIN public."POSTAL_CODE"
    SET DEFAULT '00000';
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this: value should be in single quote like '00000'

```
ALTER DOMAIN public."POSTAL_CODE" set default '00000';
```

Comment: I corrected the syntax. Somebody, please peer review my edit, please.

Comment: does it help you ?

Comment: Anyway, you could leave a note something about the difference between double and single quotes, like @jarlh did

Comment: added in answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177996/discussion-between-banan314-and-fa06).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Alter table <table name> ALTER <column name> TYPE character varying, ALTER <column name> SET DEFAULT '00000'
```

Comment: I don't have any table in my database, so what table should I use? A domain doesn't have anything to do with a table, AFAIK.

Comment: I have just trying give you syntax for further use also .. you can replace if it is not table then just remove name table  Alter DOMAIN.... and so on your query...

Comment: Do you see `ALTER TABLE` in the documentation? Check https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-alterdomain.html